# json_encode serialize null bytes

Tags: php, json

I ran into this [`serialize`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) *gotcha* today. From PHP.net doc:

> **Note:** 
>   Object's private members have the class name prepended to the member
>   name; protected members have a '*' prepended to the member name. These
>   prepended values have **null bytes on either side**.

I'm using debug_backtrace to generate a trace for a debug report, which gets `json_encode`d. Internally it uses the serializer to generate the data for the trace.

This is the (partial) output of the `json_encode`:

```
{"\u0000MyObject\u0000my_var":[]}
```

The problem is that `json_decode` can't handle this, it will complain about the null bytes.

So `json_encode` happily writes the null bytes, that `json_decode` can't decode. This seems a little wonky to me. I would expect `json_encode` takes care of the necessary escaping, or at least that `json_decode` can parse anything produced by `json_encode`, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

I guess I have several solutions:

- Strip the null bytes from the trace, I'm not so much interested in unserializing the object, I just want a string representation.
- Strip private variables all together from the trace.
- Fix `json_encode` so that it doesn't produce null bytes
- Fix `json_decode` so that it accepts null bytes

**Did anyone run into this problem and how did you fix it?**

---

**Sample:**

```
<?php
class MyClass {
    public $mypublic = 1;
    private $myprivate = 2;
    public function myfunc() {
        return debug_backtrace();
    }
}
$c = new MyClass();
$json = json_encode(call_user_func_array(array($c, "myfunc"), new MyClass()));
echo $json;
echo json_decode($json); // <-- Fatal error: Cannot access property started with '\0' in test.php on line 12
```

---

**Solution**

> Since PHP 5.3 `call_user_func_array` will throw a warning when the second
>   parameter of `call_user_func_array` is not an array. Until then you'll have to check it yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<sub>(sorry, this might be better off as a comment, as it doesn't exactly answer your question -- but it's a bit too long for that)</sub>

I've tried reproducing what you describe, with both PHP 5.3 and 5.2, and here's what I get :

First, let's create a class with a private property and instanciate it :

```
class A {
    public $pub = 10;
    private $priv = 20;
}

$a = new A();
var_dump($a);
```

Which gets me :

```
object(A)[1]
  public 'pub' => int 10
  private 'priv' => int 20
```

Now, if I `serialize()` my object :

```
$serialized = serialize($a);
var_dump($serialized);
```

I get :

```
string 'O:1:"A":2:{s:3:"pub";i:10;s:7:"�A�priv";i:20;}' (length=46)
```

Which is pretty much what you describe : there are those `null`-bytes arround the `private`-property's name.

And let's continue with `json_encode()` :

```
$jsoned = json_encode($serialized);
var_dump($jsoned);
```

Which gives me, like you said, a string with some `\u0000` :

```
string '"O:1:\"A\":2:{s:3:\"pub\";i:10;s:7:\"\u0000A\u0000priv\";i:20;}"' (length=64)
```

Now, if I try to `json_decode()` this string :

```
$unjsoned = json_decode($jsoned);
var_dump($unjsoned);
```

Here's what I get :

```
string 'O:1:"A":2:{s:3:"pub";i:10;s:7:"�A�priv";i:20;}' (length=46)
```

**=> The null-bytes don't seem to be lost : they are properly re-created from the JSON string.**

And, calling `unserialize()` on that :

```
$unserialized = unserialize($unjsoned);
var_dump($unserialized);
```

I get back the initial object I had :

```
object(A)[2]
  public 'pub' => int 10
  private 'priv' => int 20
```

So, I don't seem to reproduce your problem when serializing+encoding and the de-encoding+unserializing...

I should add that I have not been able to find anything about such a bug, in both :

- php's bug-tracker,
- and the SVN history of the json extension.

---

Now, if I try with a more complex object, with a class that contains a private member, which is itself an object which contains a private property :

```
class A {
    private $priv;
    public function __construct() {
        $this->priv = new B();
    }
}

class B {
    private $b = 10;
}
```

I get exactly the same kind of behavior : everything works just fine -- and here is the output I get, when using exactly the same actions and `var_dump()` calls as before :

```
object(A)[1]
  private 'priv' => 
    object(B)[2]
      private 'b' => int 10

string 'O:1:"A":1:{s:7:"�A�priv";O:1:"B":1:{s:4:"�B�b";i:10;}}' (length=54)

string '"O:1:\"A\":1:{s:7:\"\u0000A\u0000priv\";O:1:\"B\":1:{s:4:\"\u0000B\u0000b\";i:10;}}"' (length=84)

string 'O:1:"A":1:{s:7:"�A�priv";O:1:"B":1:{s:4:"�B�b";i:10;}}' (length=54)

object(A)[3]
  private 'priv' => 
    object(B)[4]
      private 'b' => int 10
```

Here too, I cannot reproduce the problem you describe.

---

Still, if I try this :

```
var_dump( 
    unserialize( 
        json_decode('{"\u0000MyObject\u0000my_var":[]}')
    )
);
```

I indeed get into troubles :

```
Fatal error: Cannot access property started with '\0'
```

But, thinking about it, if I try to decode it "myself", I don't really see how you'd have gotten such a JSON string...

Are you sure there is not a problem somewhere else ? Like in the encoding process ?

Comment: I'm not doing the serializing step. I was merely making the reference that it seems like json_encode is doing something similar to `serialize` when it comes to encoding private variables. The reason I'm not serializing before json_encode is because I don't really know what I'm encoding (or I don't really care). I could add a serialization step but that kind of beats the purpose of using JSON in the first place as JSON is itself a serialization. As for how you get the JSON string? Well, you just json_encode the object you made (without serializing first)

Comment: @Frits Oh, I though you were having some `serialize()` called somewhere, from what you said -- and from the null-bytes ;;; actually, `json_encode()` doesn't keep `protected` and `private` properties : only the public ones are present in the returned string. *(I've just tested ; and there are many comments about that on the `json_encode()` manual page)*

Comment: I've figured out what is causing the 'wonkiness'. I traced the code and there is a `call_user_func_array` (and `_array` is vital here). The argument that get's passed in is not an array. In my actual code it's an object that implements `Countable`, `ArrayAccess` and `IteratorAggregate`, but an object none the less. And that object has a private parameter. I guess the question now is .. now what the hell do I do? :D

Comment: I've amended the question with my solution.

Comment: Whooo ^^ I cannot try right now, but, just for, I'll try when I can (maybe tomorrow) to see what your code is exactly doing ;-)

Comment: @PascalMARTIN Hey! I've had this same issue. Apparently, PHP `json_decode`s lambda function names as `null+'lambda_'+counter`...

Comment: It's worth noting that proper null-byte decoding **doesn't** work in json-c 1.3.2. The issue is documented [here](https://github.com/json-c/json-c/issues/108) and [here](https://github.com/remicollet/pecl-json-c/issues/7).

Answer (score -2):

You could simply use a regexp to strip \u0000 from the JSON string then if you do decode it it should be ok.

Comment: `str_replace` works. It doesn't change the fact that the data is modified. You couldn't unserialize the object again if you so desired.

Comment: the JSON may include `'\\u0000'` that **not** contains null-bytes chars

Answer (score -2):

try changing encoding to utf8. I assume you're taking data from database

```
mysql_query('SET CHARACTER SET utf8');
```

it should work. If it won'T, try to escape null characters before decoding your object

```
preg_replace('|\\u0000|', ' ', $json);
```

if it won't work, try this

```
<?php
$json = '{"\u0000MyObject\u0000my_var":[]}';
$json = preg_replace('/\\\\u([0-9A-F]{4})/i', '', $json);
$json = json_decode($json);
print_r($json);
```

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/684be.php

Comment: I'm not. Encoding is not the problem. The null bytes are INTENTIONALLY being produced by the serializer. And ideally I'd want them preserved.

Comment: No, you don't need a regular expression here. The only problematic encoding is `\u0000`, the other ones are fine. Thanks for trying though. And of course this solution works. I'm just wondering which is the best solution.

Comment: I know it works, I listed it as the known solutions. But it doesn't answer my question ;)

Comment: "Did anyone run into this problem and how did you fix it?" <-- " how did you fix it?"