# Character added to JSON string

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I am using `jQuery.parseJSON()` to parse a response from `jQuery.ajax()` call to a PHP script.
The code works except on some server the characters `0000` are inserted at the start of the response string causing `jQuery.parseJSON()` to fail.

I can not figure how those character are being inserted, any ideas?
The characters are not in the PHP encoded string before echoing response.

Here is the scenario:

PHP script creates JSON string with:

```
$html = json_encode(myArrayOfValues);
echo $html
```

jQuery.ajax receives encoded string in:

```
....success: function(html, textStatus){
        var response = jQuery.parseJSON(html);
....
```

To fixed the problem I added function that removes inserted characters and changed:

```
var response = jQuery.parseJSON(html);
```

to:

```
var response = parseJSONResponse(html);
```

Where:

```
function parseJSONResponse(html){

    var foundChar =  html.indexOf("{");

    if(foundChar > 0 ){
        html = html.substring(foundChar);
    }

    var response = jQuery.parseJSON(html);

    return response;
}
```

Ultimately, it works but I'd like to know where the inserted characters are coming from and if there is a way to prevent them being inserted.

Comment: Please read the [how to edit question and answer help guide](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Comment: Dammit Felix, you're quick on the edits today. :)

Comment: Do you have any other `echo`s in the file? Are you using a server-side framework? What server are you using?

Comment: 1) What does the raw response look like in Firebug/Inspector or when you directly request the URL? 2) You should be passing the `dataType` (docs: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ ) option to your ajax call so that it is already parse when your success method receives it.

Comment: First create a PHP with only those two lines and see if it still happens.

Comment: Could be related to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731086/json-encode-serialize-null-bytes

Comment: Sorry, I did not see replies until now. There are no other echo statements. Site is running in Joomla 1.5.26. Server varies. Not using firebug, but string before echo does not have anything in front of JSON string. DataType is set to html.

Comment: Also, not related to null bytes question 6731086. In my case the 0000 are added to the beginning of the JSON string like 0000{...} vs the problem problem null bytes inside the string.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a character encoding related issue. \u0000 is the NULL character. Although this could just be a coincidence it seems worth looking into.

I think the preferred character encoding for json is utf-8. Try adding this to the head of your calling page and see if it resolves the issue:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Hope that helps!